# Anchor not working in iframe, but works fine outside of it

Tags: html, iframe, anchor

For a web site I'm trying to improve, I have an anchor in an IFrame document.  One the main page, the anchor tag does not respond.  On other pages which also embed this same iframe document, it does respond.  By itself, all links in the iframe document work when the page is loaded directly.  Also, if I trim significant content from the main page, the anchor links work.  I found no errors in the web developer log.  I'm using FF 31.0, but IE didn't work any better.  Also, the page is HTML 5.

Rather than post the actual HTML, please see page at
dreamfloatmassagespa.com  (this is the main page)
and dreamfloatmassagespa.com/FloatingPage.html  (this is one of the working pages)

I've tried adding the sandbox attribute, but FF doesn't care in this case.  Both the IFrame and the parent frame refer to locations on the same domain.  The links in question point to actual web locations and not Javascript functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your div with class .row are above everything in your main content, that's why you cant click in any anchor inside the main content in the mainPage.html. Probably you did some mistake in your css in the MainPage.html.

Comment: Thanks that did help quite a bit.